# How do missing geometry errors arise using osmnx.plot_graph_folium()?

Tags: python, geopandas, osmnx

I'm seeing the error

`AttributeError: No geometry data set yet (expected in column 'geometry'.`

and based on the code snippets in the stack trace, this is because `osmnx.plot_graph_folium()` converts the provided graph to a GeoDataFrame before plotting.

Inspecting the graph that was generated via `osmnx.graph_from_address()`, I can easily find edges lacking a `'geometry'` attribute.

Why do some edges in a graph created by `osmnx` lack geometry information, and how should this gracefully be handled by `plot_graph_folium()`?

I am using using OSMNX version 0.11.4 with NetworkX 2.6.2 and GeoPandas 0.6.3

Comment: Please provide a complete, minimal, reproducible code snippet so others can troubleshoot and answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to troubleshoot this without a reproducible code snippet. But it generally shouldn't throw an error if it runs into some edges without a `geometry` attribute. OSMnx only creates geometry attributes for edges that are *not* straight lines between two endpoints, because otherwise the geometry is trivial.

```py
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_place('Piedmont, California, USA', network_type='drive')

# how many edges are there?
print(len(G.edges))  # 933

# how many edges have a geometry attribute?
print(sum(['geometry' in d for u, v, d in G.edges(data=True)]))  # 672

# this works fine, without errors
ox.plot_graph_folium(G)
```